# C bitwise operator '&' uses

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 (5%5)?1:0&puts("fizz");

}
```

The code above prints `fizz` as expected. But I don't understand how the bitwise `&` operand works with  `0&puts("fizz")`. What is the working behind it? What is the value of the  expression?

Someone please explain

Comment: Instead of  `&` try with `&&` you will find interesting result

Comment: I will consider this for my next if-else-statements :)

Answer (score 4):

1. `(5%5)` is evaluated to `0` which is false.
2. The whole statement then evaluates to `0&puts("fizz");`
3. To evaluate that, the value `0` is bitwise AND'd with the return value of `puts` which can only be found by executing the function which prints fizz.
4. The result (which will always be `0`) is discarded.

Comment: You may note that the result, if returned or store in a variable will be `0` since `0 & anything` is just 0.

Comment: I think it's worth to note why using && would behave differently

Answer (score 3):

The expression:

```
(5 % 5)?    1  : 0 & puts("fizz"); 
   ^              ^      
   0 == False     executes
```

puts prints: `"fizz"`. The returned value from puts function is bitwise & with `0` and result (that should be `0`) is discarded.

So your expression is equivalent to  `(5 % 5)?    1  :  puts("fizz");` in effects.

Comment: in-fact just `puts("fizz");` because value of `5 % 5` determined at compilation time.

Comment: I don't think there's such a guarantee anywhere.

Comment: @unwind yes I am not sure to, I tried to observe optimized asm code and found this doesn't optimized to puts() statement.

Answer (score 2):

Well ... `5 % 5` is 0 (false), so the `?:` part goes on to evaluate the expression to the right of the colon.

That means evaluating 0 bitwise-and:ed with the return value of `puts()`, so obviously the function must be called.

Answer (score 0):

The `puts()` function returns a non-negative number if it completes successfully. This non-negative number is then ANDed with the zero.

Answer (score 0):

The `puts()` returns a non-negative number when sucessful. `if (5%5)` will return false. Therefore, the return value from `puts()` is bitwise `&` with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` forces the `puts()` to be excuted.